# BigInteger in Groovy

Tags: groovy, integer, biginteger

I want to add up all numbers from 1 to 1000000.

```
range = 1..1000000
println range.each { it * it }.sum()
```

As a result I get 1784293664 instead of 500000500000. I assume, I need a BigInteger. But when I try

```
range = 1..1000000
println range.each { it * it }.sum().toBigInteger()
```

nothing changes.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The `.each { it * it }` part is redundant, as the result of that multiplication is discarded. BTW the sum of the integers from 1 to n can also be expressed as `((n + 1) * n) / 2`, which will make things easier for the computer :) ([kindof-amusing story of Little Gauss coming up with that result](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57919.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range is of type `IntRange`. Here's a correct one:

```
range = 1G..1000000G
println range.each { it * it }.sum()
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help.

Comment: That helped, thank you.  In fact, even `range = 1..1000000L` worked.

Answer (score 4):

You've done the sum, which has the same (truncated) error, and then converted that erroneous answer to a `BigInteger`. It was wrong before it was converted. What makes you think `BigInteger` is going to magically be able to recover the lost precision? :-)

Comment: So could you please give me an advice, where to convert to BigInteger?

Comment: I think doing "it as BigInteger * it as BigInteger" should do it.   Actually since you souldn't lose percision and should auto-promote, {it as BigInteger * it} should work too

Comment: It throws an `MultipleCompilationErrorsException` because of an `unexpected token`...

Answer (score 2):

You can create BigInteger literals with the G suffix: e.g. `1G..1000000G`.  There's no need for the `each` expression.

```
(1G..1000000G).sum()
```

Do you want to add up the *squares* of those numbers?  If so, you should be calling `collect` rather than `each`.  When you iterate over the range with `each`, the expression you're calculating (`it * it`) gets discarded.  In this case it would look like:

```
(1G..1000000G).collect { it * it }.sum()
```

Note that `collect` forces the range to be evaluated eagerly and creates a large collection in memory.  You may want to consider using `inject` to calculate it incrementally:

```
(1G..1000000G).inject(0, { sum, value -> sum + value * value } )
```